# change the font of table caption

Tags: captions, fontsize

In my poster doing with baposter, I need to change a font of some figures.

I know that we can use \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} to cnfigure the font of the caption.

In a specific figure I used this code to put the font to `\tiny`

```
 \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{ball.png}
      \captionof{figure}{\tiny \textbf{caption}}
```

I got this result:

[image]
I need to get the "Figure 3 " as \tiny? can you help me please? sorry I can not post all my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not make changes directly in the `\caption` argument; instead, you can use `\captionsetup` locally (inside the environment); unfortunately? (seee below) `tiny` is not one of the predefined font sizes, but you can easily implement it using `\DeclareCaptionFont`; an example including some of your general settings for caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{tiny}{\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{test caption in \texttt{small} font size}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
B
\captionsetup{font=tiny}
\caption{test caption in \texttt{tiny} font size}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can introduce any other font, style, etc. modifications required in `\captionsetup`.

As a side note, a caption with such small font would be really hard to read.

Comment: what if I want to set the font size as 11pt?

Comment: and I have to write that code for every caption figure right ? isn't a way to do this just one time for the whole tex document ?

Comment: You can define it once and then use in the whole document.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks